# Does Safari have the feature "Select an element in the page to inspect it" as Chrome does?

Tags: safari

In Chrome, there is a very useful feature:

[image]

But I can't find it for Safari Browser. Is it possible to do that in Safari?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]Yes, Safari (I'm using 10.1.1 on Sierra) has it, and it is the same shortcut (command shift c). You may need to have the debug and/or develop menu enabled. The debug console can be reached by pressing command option u.

Comment: Not the same shortcut for those who are used to the shorcut cmd+alt+c ;)
Guess I'll start using cmd+shift+c

Comment: This doesn't appear to work within Google Docs because the webapp has hijacked the keyboard shortcut.